# eclipse unable to generate design view from java source

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have the following situation

I have one swt class which displays a simple window in one project. In this project i am able to see the design view and code view separately. Now in another project i am copying and pasting the class that i developed in previous project (same IDE at a same time). As a result it is not able to show the design view for the swt class.

Another scenario of the problem is that when one swt class is designed on one machine and if i import that project in my IDE from other machine using external media then also it is not able to show me the designer view for the swt class.

How can i solve this problem? Is there any standard solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after being familiar with eclipse one day i come to know that we can do `Open With -> GWT Designer` to view the design part of the SWT form in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a stupid question, but did you try to do right click, and open with a visual Editor, or something like that?

Or maybe you copy only the code in a not-visual class...

Comment: There is no such option. To be specif i am using eclipse IDE.